# Why do I have intermittent Wi-Fi disconnections in Ubuntu 20.04.6?

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6 and have been experiencing intermittent Wi-Fi disconnections during which my Wi-Fi icon turns into a question mark.

I was able to get all the below information before my WIFI automatically reconnected:

- Output of `ifconfig -a`:

  ```
  eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          ether ec:8e:b5:45:a7:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
          inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
          inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
          loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
          RX packets 96567  bytes 8206625 (8.2 MB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 96567  bytes 8206625 (8.2 MB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
          inet6 2606:a800:cf85:1a00:76e6:5d29:86fc:8d7e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
          inet6 fe80::20fc:fa07:8117:1c33  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
          inet6 2606:a800:cf85:1a00:c56d:f38c:137a:80e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>       ether 40:49:0f:48:d6:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 1558979  bytes 1007454192 (1.0 GB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 918856  bytes 168900180 (168.9 MB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```
- Output of `ping 192.168.0.1` (this is the IP of my router):

  ```
  PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
  From 192.168.0.20 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
  From 192.168.0.20 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
  From 192.168.0.20 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
  From 192.168.0.20 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
  ^C
  --- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
  6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5065ms
  pipe 3
  ```
- Output of `service network-manager status`:

  ```
  ● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-12-09 15:42:03 EST; 7h ago
         Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
     Main PID: 799 (NetworkManager)
        Tasks: 3 (limit: 4485)
       Memory: 10.2M
       CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
               └─799 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6390] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6390] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6391] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_routers    => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6391] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6392] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6392] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6392] dhcp4 (wlo1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6393] dhcp4 (wlo1): option routers              => '192.168.0.1'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6393] dhcp4 (wlo1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
  Dec 09 22:54:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702180491.6393] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed extended -> extended
  ```
- Output of `iwconfig`:

  ```
  wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"patawad"
            Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: C0:C5:22:4C:9E:D0
            Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
            Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
            Power Management:off
            Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm
            Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
            Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:4   Missed beacon:0
  ```
- Output of `nmcli dev wifi`:

  ```
  IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
  *       C0:C5:22:4C:9E:D0  patawad           Infra  6     54 Mbit/s   100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
          94:18:65:49:D5:1B  skeetswifi_2GEXT  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
          6C:AE:F6:C5:CC:64  9755a8            Mesh   6     270 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA3
          6C:AE:F6:C5:CC:67  skeetswifi        Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
          6C:AE:F6:C5:CC:6A  --                Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  --
  ```
- And lastly, the network log before failure at Dec 09 21:22:35 (**`<warn>`**):

  ```
  $ sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
  Dec 09 21:09:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174191.6197] dhcp4 (wlo1): option routers              => '192.168.0.1'
  Dec 09 21:09:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174191.6198] dhcp4 (wlo1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
  Dec 09 21:09:51 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174191.6198] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed extended -> extended
  Dec 09 21:22:35 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <warn>  [1702174955.9205] sup-iface[0x557d363c1920,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
  Dec 09 21:22:35 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174955.9537] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
  Dec 09 21:22:35 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174955.9538] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
  Dec 09 21:22:36 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174956.0225] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
  Dec 09 21:22:36 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174956.0228] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
  Dec 09 21:22:36 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174956.9985] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
  Dec 09 21:22:36 ubuntu20 NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1702174956.9986] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
  ```

Why does my Wi-Fi get disconnected?

Comment: Judging from the bitrate and security stats, are you running [IEEE 802.11g-2003 (WiFi 3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11g-2003)? This standard is 20 years old, and for this reason (and several others), I would suggest you upgrade your WiFi access point to at least WiFi 5 or 6, and then see how that works for you.

Comment: @beastofcaerbannog Thanks for the edit 

Comment: My pleasure @stumblebee ! 

Comment: @ArturMeinild That sounds like a good idea. I'll try that out. Thx!